# ant error while compiling typedef A class needed by class IvyAntSettings cannot be found

Tags: java, ant, ivy

I have an ant project with build.xml and ivy.xml setup.

when I run the "ant" command line or I use intellij to build the jar (with -compile) I am getting this error:

```
BUILD FAILED
build.xml : the following error occurred while executing this line:
jar:file:/C:/java/jdk1.8.0_351/jre/lib/ext/ivy-2.3.0.jar!/org/apache/ivy/ant/antlib.xml:21: type def A class needed by class org.apache.ivy.IvySettings cannot be found: org/apache/tools/types/DataType using the classloader AntClassLoader[]
...
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/tools/types/DataType
```

I tried ivy version 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.5.0, 2.5.1, ant version 1.10.5, 1.10.10, 1.10.12.

My ANT_*HOME and JAVA*_*HOME are set properly and ANT_*HOME is in PATH

I can create run configuration and the service runs properly, I can access API/REST, no compile errors.

I am not sure what else to check

Comment: Welcome to SO! Make sure to ask an actual question. Don't make us guess what your question is, even though you might think it's obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is I had the jar files in multiple location. I removed it from the $ANT_HOME/lib/ant/lib folder and it worked.